# How to Inject Axios in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios, puppeteer

I want to inject axios in puppeteer in order to open a browser session, but sending requests and receiving responses through axios:

So the question is, is it possible? Here's my attempt, but it is not working since axios doesn't intercepts the website responses

```
const axios = require('axios');
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

(async () =>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://InstanceOfUrl.com/something.php')
    const res = await axios.get('https://InstanceOfUrl.com/something.php?action=examples/foo')
    const data = res.data
    console.log(data)
})()
```

I'm moving my first steps in axios, so I beg you to be patient; Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) api? We're not in 2010 anymore :)

Comment: Is it better? Which advantages can you take from that? can you show me some code in order to see how to inject it in puppeteer (if you need to inject it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to go into a more verbose version using Promises:

- combining with @Simon's advise using `fetch`

```
puppeteer
  .launch({headless:false})
  .then(browser => browser.newPage())
  .then(page => page.goto('https://InstanceOfUrl.com/something.php'))
  .then(() => fetch('https://InstanceOfUrl.com/something.php?action=examples/foo')
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => {
    throw new Error(error.message);
   })
  .finally(() => browser.close());
```

This will allow you to reason about each object passed into the next `.then` in the promise chain.

Hope it helps

Comment: Okk is it possible to do in headless mode as well?

Comment: Yes, by using `.launch({ headless: true })`

Comment: 2 periods before the catch breaks it